# Load local images into an array asynchronously on iOS

Tags: ios, swift, grand-central-dispatch, dispatch-async

I need to load about 200 images in my bundle into an array in memory like this:

`let arr = (0..<200).map({UIImage(named: "\($0).png")})`

The only problem with this is it takes forever to do.. so I'd like to do it in the background and get a callback when the job finishes..

I suppose I can do it like this:

`var arr = []
DispatchQueue.main.async({
  arr = (0..<200).map({UIImage(named: "\($0).png")})
})`

But then how would I know when the block completes? Thanks!

EDIT: I need to load of these into memory because I want animate a series of images in `UIImageView` like this:

```
let img: UIImageView()
img.animationImages = arr
img.duration = 1
img.startAnimating()
```

Comment: this will load 200 UIImages into memory at once. if the images are not really small your app will probably crash due to memory issues

Comment: They are small -- I've tried them and it doesn't crash. Just takes forever like I stated.

Comment: Why do you need all of it in memory? Better to create an array of urls

Comment: Try loading the images from the fileURL instead of using the named initializer

Comment: Why need to do this? Its bad practice

Comment: @LeoDabus : Hi i have around 180 images and need to show it in imageview using imageview.startanimating() method. But my app crashes due to memory issues. Can you please help me.

Comment: You can try loading them from disk using UIImage(contentsOfFile: String) initializer. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimage/1624112-init This method loads the image data into memory and marks it as purgeable. If the data is purged and needs to be reloaded, the image object loads that data again from the specified path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a callback and call it after loading the images on the background thread, since the images will be loaded synchronously there.

I recommend doing something like this:

```
func loadImages(callback: @escaping ([UIImage]) -> Void) {
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
        let array = (0..<200).flatMap({ UIImage(named: "\($0).png") })
        callback(array)
    }
}
```

Which can be used like this (using swift trailing closure syntax):

```
loadImages { images in
    // do something with the images
}
```

You might have to dispatch the `callback(array)` back to the `DispatchQueue.main`.

Comment: Yep this is what I ended up doing. It worked out nicely. Thanks for posting anyway - accepted your answer!